# How to implement Error with a custom struct

Tags: error-handling, rust, traits, lifetime, borrow-checker

I was following along [here](https://stevedonovan.github.io/rust-gentle-intro/6-error-handling.html#basic-error-handling).

It contains a simplified example which seemed relevant, but my implementation doesn't lend itself well.  The error here is: `returns a reference to data owned by the current function`.  The example suggests using a specific attribute of a struct, which is a `String`.  This is fine because the compiler can know how long that struct will last.  But what if we need to build the string at runtime?  How do I make this work?

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub enum ReadFailure {
    MissingFile(String),
    BadData(String),
    // ...
}

impl fmt::Display for ReadFailure {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            ReadFailure::MissingFile(path) => write!(f, "WARNING - File not read (file does not exist): {}", path),
            ReadFailure::BadData(path) => write!(f, "WARNING - File cannot be read (file has bad data): {}", path),
            // ...
        }
    }
}

/// Implements an error for failure to read with a message
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct ReadError {
    /// Failure condition
    error: ReadFailure,
}

impl fmt::Display for ReadError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.error)
    }
}

impl Error for ReadError {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        let s = format!("{}", self.error);
        &s
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not have to implement `description`. The rustdoc says: "deprecated since 1.42.0: use the Display impl or to_string() " https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#method.description.

You will have more flexibility when implementing `Display`, i.e. you can use the [write_str](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.write_str) method on `Formatter`.

Comment: @justinas I'm going to try this, but I think this is exactly what I needed to know.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

> But what if we need to build the string at runtime? How do I make this work?

Just build it at run-time when you create the `ReadError`, here's an example:

```rust
use std::fmt;
use std::error::Error;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub enum ReadFailure {
    MissingFile(String),
    BadData(String),
}

impl fmt::Display for ReadFailure {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            ReadFailure::MissingFile(path) => write!(f, "WARNING - File not read (file does not exist): {}", path),
            ReadFailure::BadData(path) => write!(f, "WARNING - File cannot be read (file has bad data): {}", path),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct ReadError {
    error: ReadFailure,
    description: String, // NEW
}

// NEW
impl ReadError {
    fn new(error: ReadFailure) -> Self {
        ReadError {
            description: error.to_string(),
            error,
        }
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for ReadError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.error)
    }
}

impl Error for ReadError {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        &self.description
    }
}

fn main() {
    // example
    let error = ReadError::new(ReadFailure::MissingFile("./whatever.txt".to_string()));
    println!("{}", error.description());
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d9fc262c88857d2e8166eb30c5ecfdd6)

It's clear from `description`'s function signature that it's only suppose to be a read-only method that returns a reference to some field within the error.

Anyway, as @justinas pointed out in the comments that method is deprecated and the docs recommend implementing the `Display` trait instead which you're already doing.

Comment: Ya.  I think the real solution is just to implement Display.  If I have to include another description, I'd really only want to do that as an option to override the default string.  With the way this is setup, though, I think it makes more sense to remove the Error block.  Thank you so much for replying, though!